# How to add a keyboard navigation to a Flash AS3 based app?

Tags: actionscript-3, navigation, keyboard

I would like to make my Flash AS3 based app more accessible with a keyboard navigation. 
What's the best way to add to every MovieClip with a `MouseEvent.CLICK` the ability to get selected through the `TAB` and *clicked/fired* through `ENTER`?

Some basic example of my code:

```
nav.btna.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openSection);
dialog.btnx.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeDialog);

function openSection(event:Event=null):void
{
    trace("nav.btna")
}

function closeDialog(event:Event=null):void
{
    trace("dialog.btnx")
}
```

I remember that there was a AS3 function that enabled that every MovieClip with a MouseEvent could be fire through ENTER if the MovieClip was selected with TAB. I can't remeber the function though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be that you are attempting this with a `MovieClip` instead of a button (`Button` or `SimpleButton`).

I made a simple test by creating buttons instead of MovieClips in my library and this worked as expected:

```
// I have 4 buttons (button1, button2, etc) on the stage
for(var i:int = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    var mc = getChildByName("button" + (i+1));
    mc.tabIndex = i;
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClicked);
}

function onClicked(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    trace(e.currentTarget + " clicked");
}

stage.focus = stage;
```

I initially ran this test with `MovieClip` instances, and while they would show that the tab was working (a yellow border shows up), the `MouseEvent.CLICK` was never firing. Once I switched to actual buttons (`SimpleButton` in this case), it worked with both the Enter and Space keys.

**EDIT:**

To answer the question posed in the comments, this is a quick-and-dirty way to "convert" MovieClips to SimpleButtons at runtime:

```
// I have 4 MovieClips (button1, button2, etc) on the stage
for(var i:int = 1; i <= 4; i++)
{
    var mc:MovieClip = getChildByName("button" + i) as MovieClip;
    var button:SimpleButton = convertMovieClipToButton(mc);
    button.tabIndex = i;
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClicked);
}

function convertMovieClipToButton(mc:MovieClip):SimpleButton
{
    var className:Class = getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(mc)) as Class;
    var button:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton(new className(), new className(), new className(), new className());
    button.name = mc.name;
    button.x = mc.x;
    button.y = mc.y;
    mc.parent.addChildAt(button, getChildIndex(mc));
    mc.parent.removeChild(mc);
    return button;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! Is there a way to change MovieClips to Buttons/SimpleButtons at runtime?